# Create X tables by looping with HtmlGenericControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmlgenericcontrol

I'm trying to create 10 different tables, but I only end up with a single one.

```
HtmlGenericControl table = new HtmlGenericControl("table");
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    table.ID = "Serie_table_" + i;
    table.Attributes.Add("class", "Serie_table");
    divSerie_lists.Controls.Add(table);
}
```

I would like the following result:

```
<table id="Serie_table_1" class="Serie_table">
<table id="Serie_table_2" class="Serie_table">
<table id="Serie_table_3" class="Serie_table">
<table id="Serie_table_4" class="Serie_table">
```

But I end up with this:

```
<table id="Serie_table_4" class="Serie_table"/>
```

I hope you can help me loop though - and create the tables correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the same object 4 times. Instead you need to create 4 different objects:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    HtmlGenericControl table = new HtmlGenericControl("table");
    table.ID = "Serie_table_" + i;
    table.Attributes.Add("class", "Serie_table");
    divSerie_lists.Controls.Add(table);
}
```

Also you can use [HtmlTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than `HtmlGenericControl`.

Comment: @user3489698: Glad to hear it helped! :)